# What does "careabouts" mean?

Tags: expressions, idioms, slang

What does "careabouts" mean? I saw it in a LinkedIn video regarding jobs, workplace, etc.

I searched all dictionaries but got nothing! I even got nothing on Google! Like such a thing doesn't exist!

"Identify his careabouts" for instance.

Does it simply refer to things somebody cares about?

Comment: I've never seen it before, but it's presumably a trivial "nonce-word" coinage meaning ***the things he cares about***, humorously modelled after *his **whereabouts*** (where he is, his location). I kinda doubt you'll find a definition in any dictionaries.

Comment: It appears to be a term used in marketing: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22careabouts%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2011,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en#ip=1

Comment: @user66974: All bar one of the results on the first page of your linked search are from a connected series of "academic" tomes with the same wide range of international authors (not necessarily native Anglophones). But my guess is it's *such* a trivial nonce-word that it's been coined many times over the years, often with slightly different connotations.

Comment: I've seen this as workplace jargon, unfortunately. Like "we should capture the careabouts so we can leverage lessons learned in the go-forward."

Comment: The expression ["customer careabouts"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22customer+careabouts%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBvsNCYOMKxmqqBURYknrSblf0-H9g:1649786707676&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF9am1jo_3AhVol3IEHVyxASkQpwV6BAgBECM&biw=1065&bih=654&dpr=1.25), for example, goes back to about 1990 in Google Books.

Comment: @FF As non-standard and with no recognised references, should this be CV-d?

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/care+about), ***care about*** (with a space in between) means:

> 2. To be **interested in** or concerned about someone or something. [...]

Looking at the usage of the single word, ***careabout(s)***, from multiple sources, the meaning of the term leans more towards someone's "needs", "requirements", the [things that someone *cares about*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/587515/what-does-careabouts-mean/587521#comment1472448_587515) or the things that someone is *interested in*.

> David Grenley passes along a new word being tossed about in Silicon Valley: "**careabouts**," a noun having nothing to do with caribou but meaning "**things we care about**."
>
> (From an [article by Leah Garchik](https://www.ctinsider.com/entertainment/article/LEAH-GARCHIK-S-PERSONALS-3319348.php) on CT Insider)

> *How would you define success?*
>
> Success to me can be defined in so many ways. If we are talking about work, for me it is very important to work on something I am passionate about to truly feel successful. I know that if I do something less in line with my **interests** or **careabouts**, I would still want to excel at it but I would not feel truly successful. I think the drive is more important that the accomplishment.
>
> (From an [interview with Lorena Marciano](https://www.womenat.com/w-at-digital-interviews) on womenat.com)

> The key **careabouts** of developers in this area include:
>
> - Programmable image processing engine with good information processing capacity (combs/union of sheer signal processing power with cognitive processing).
> - Easy to program environment/developing tools.
>
> (From [Media Processors](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=5v5SAAAAMAAJ&q=%22careabouts%22&dq=%22careabouts%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9htiqlY_3AhUQyYsBHT_sCjw4ChDoAXoECAkQAg) by SPIE, 2001)

> 2. Readiness for critical self-appraisal will be made easier if a range of voices and opinions have opportunities to be heard. Are the aspects of practice chosen those that really matter to the key stakeholders — their '**careabouts**'? Knowing what they **really care about**, and consensus about aspects of school life that should be benchmarked, is part of the process of creating a receptive self-evaluating climate.
>
> (From [Self-Evaluation: What's In It For Schools?](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=R1EzaAIPorcC&pg=PT97&dq=%22careabouts%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9htiqlY_3AhUQyYsBHT_sCjw4ChDoAXoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22careabouts%22&f=false) by John MacBeath and Archie Mcglynn)

> As the customer and market assessment team members gain clarity on your current and future customers and their requirements, their counterparts interviewing in the area of strategic planning trace how well your management system (1) defines competitive and market strategies and (2) links action plans in all work units and processes with the few vital **customer requirements** or "**careabouts**."
>
> (From [Management Systems and Organizational Performance [...]](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ZNDPbYMhIGcC&pg=PA252&dq=%22careabouts%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIuY6Bl4_3AhWHyYsBHSQpCHI4FBDoAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22careabouts%22&f=false) by Martin F. Stankard)